# Drupal add link to another page in header of a block

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-blocks

In Drupal 7 I created a views page, and I want users to have the option to view the results either as a list, or with thumbnails (like on a lot of websites). The only way I can think of doing that is creating one page with the results as a list, and having a link to another page with the results that have thumbnails.

But my question is, how do I add just a random link to the top of my block page that will direct users to the 'thumbnail' page?

I tried to use 'unfiltered text' in the header and put the html for a link in there, and when I went to the page it *looked* like a link, but I couldn't click it. Any suggestions?

Comment: unfiltered text in header should work to add some html. Did you check the html source code produced by drupal ? Seems odd it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

For every view you can create set of templates to style it. When you edit you view open "Advanced options" and then at bottom click on "Theming options" (or suggestions...can't remember real text).

That way you'll get a very useful popup which displays all templates used by view...in specific theme. So if you want to change some template just click on it's original name, pick up it's original code (copy) and create a file. Save it at your theme templates directory, pick some of suggested names, add your link or what ever html you need and clear the cache.

Templating is a bit broad subject to discuss in details for you questions's answer - find some tutorial on net, but general idea is to use custom view template and store your html there.

BTW, I hope you have only one view and different displays for you different pages.